# rails with mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

Anyone know of a book covering rails 3 & Mongoid/MongoDB. Something along the lines of how    to approach common problems through a document oriented approach over RDM.

I practice tuotorial from http://openmymind.net/mongodb.pdf
Now i want some real example with rails using mongodb.
anything like links,tuotorials, book is heartly welcome..

answer should cover
where to define database connection
   select certain data from databse.

Answer (score 2):

The MongoDB wiki lists [available books](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Books).  Given how quickly software like MongoDB, Rails, and Mongoid are evolving it is probably going to be difficult to find a current book (or one that will remain current for long). Online resources may be a better bet if you want to learn and work with the newest versions.

Some suggested starting points:

- The [Mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/) includes plenty of examples; there is also a sample app [Echo](https://github.com/mongoid/echo).
- The [MongoDB wiki](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home) and [MongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) include detailed information, examples, and links to other resources such as blog posts and presentations.
- The [RailsApps Project](http://railsapps.github.com/) includes a number of helpful tutorials and sample apps using Mongoid (as well as other useful tools and gems).